# How to use ClickHouse partition value in SQL query?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table with tuple partitions: `(0, 0)`, `(0, 1)`, `(1, 0)`, `(1, 1)`, `(2, 0)`, `(2, 1)`, `(3, 0)`, ...

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    id Int32,
    a Int32,
    b Float32,
    c Int32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY
(
    intDiv(id, 1000000),
    a < 20000 AND b > 0.6 AND c >= 100
)
ORDER BY id;
```

I need only rows with partition `(<any number>, 1)` and I'm looking for a way to use partition value in a query like

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE my_table.partition[2] == 1;
```

Does ClickHouse have such a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version [21.6](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/whats-new/changelog/#clickhouse-release-21-6-2021-06-05) was added virtual columns     *_partition_id* and *_partition_value* that can help you:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    _partition_id,
    _partition_value
FROM my_table
WHERE (_partition_value.2) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

And what is the problem with

```
where (a < 20000 AND b > 0.6 AND c >= 100) = 1
```

???

```
insert into my_table select 1, 3000000, 0, 0 from numbers(100000000);
insert into my_table select 1, 0, 10, 200 from numbers(100);

SET send_logs_level = 'debug';
set force_index_by_date=1;

select sum(id) from my_table where (a < 20000 AND b > 0.6 AND c >= 100) = 1;
           
...Selected 1/7 parts by partition key...

┌─sum(id)─┐
│     100 │
└─────────┘
1 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.
```

Though `(_partition_value.2) = 1` will be faster because it does not require to read columns a,b,c for filtering.

Comment: The problem in amount of rows to scan. A condition on partition value will skip rows in other partitions without any checks.

Comment: Because of partition pruning CH reads only related partitions.